# The name 'AntiForgery' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, antiforgerytoken

I am Trying to implement Antifrogery Token in my Web Api but getting following error:

The name 'AntiForgery' does not exist in the current context.

Here is My code:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
namespace MyAPI
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute: FilterAttribute
{

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        try
        {
            string cookieToken = "";
            string formToken = "";
            //I am getting error on the line written below for  "AntiForgery":
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
        }
        catch
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                RequestMessage = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request
            };
            return FromResult(actionContext.Response);
        }
        return continuation();
    }

    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> FromResult(HttpResponseMessage result)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        source.SetResult(result);
        return source.Task;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: System.Web.Helpers namespace is needed here.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya i am using that but even then problem persists.

Comment: Make sure you've included the reference and added it to the using statement?

Comment: I have added in into reference and included namespaces with "using System.Web.Helpers;" statement.

Comment: AntiForgery.Validate() seems to be obsolete. Not very sure if this is the issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568796(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Can you please clarify which reference you added specifically?

Comment: Installed "PM> Install-Package System-Web-Helpers.dll" and added "System.Web.Helpers".

Comment: [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery(v=vs.111).aspx), `AntiForgery` is part of the `System.Web.WebPages` assembly, not the `System.Web.Helpers`.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 2):

namespace System.Web.Helpers is exist in some assembly.

You must add System.Web.WebPages assembly to your project and then add a new using statement like this:

*Solution Explorer -> [Project] -> References -> (right click) Add Reference... -> Extensions (Tab) -> System.Web.WebPages -> Add*

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
```

Comment: all correct, but make sure that you use Version=2.0.0.0
'AntiForgery' exist only in this version.

Comment: Had the same reference issue, because my project had System.Web.Helpers v1.0.0.0 in the references.  Need to make sure your version of System.Web.Helpers is version 3.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add namespace "using System.Web.Helpers;".
2. Install package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" in the Nuget packages.
3. Add Reference "System.Web" to the project.